# Inverse Hausdorff Young

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

We all know the classic Hausdorff Young inequality for fourier series

$\|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^q}\leq\|f\|_{L^p}$,

where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $p\in[1,2]$.

My question is: is there any result related to the "inverse" inequality $\|f\|_{L^p}\leq\|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^q}$ with $q\in[1,2]$ ?

Any help or advice would be helpful.

Comment: It seems true for $q=1$ (by the triangle inequality) and $q=2$ (by Parseval). So for $q\in[1,2]$ it just follows from interpolation, specifically the Riesz-Thorin theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**First** you need to note that Hausdorff-Young holds for $1\le p\le 2$, not for all $p$. If it held for all $p\in[1,\infty]$ the "inverse" inequality would be a trivial consequence.

The inverse inequality is false, even with a constant factor added. For example let $f=\sin(t)/t$. Then (if you put the $2\pi$'s in the right place in your definition of the Fourier transform) $\hat f=\chi_{[-1,1]}$. So $\hat f\in L^\infty$ but $ f\notin L^1$, so the inequality $||f||_1\le c||\hat f||_\infty$ is false.

Comment: In fact, it is known that $L^p$ and $L^q$ are nonisomorphic for $p\ne 2$, thus the Fourier transform (and its inverse) can't be bounded from $L^p\to L^q$ for $p>2$, at least on the whole line. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I agree with you. However, I forgot to put the condition $1\leq q \leq 2$ when you read the question. I edited the question by entering this condition now. In this case it is reasonable to occur the inequality mentioned since $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq\|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^1}$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "In this case it is reasonable to occur the inequality mentioned". Because $||\hat f||_\infty\le||f||_1$ is an instance of H-Y, not "inverse H-Y"...

Comment: $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq \|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^1}$ is an instance of "inverse" H-Y with $q=1$ and $p=\infty$. See page 204-Fourier Analysis and PDE - Iório, Iório